# Why did I got 2 different feature map with the same kernel on the same image?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-detection

I took a kernel at random, and applied it to an image with padding='valid', stride=(1,1), the kernel was of size = (3,3).

This was the normal image:

[image]

This is the image after applying the filter:

[image]

Then I rotated the original image by 90 degrees, and it changed to this:

[image]

Then I applied the same filter on this rotated image, and got this as the output:

[image]

And then I rotated this output image, so that its rotation is the same as previous feature map.
After I rotated this rotated-feature map, and compared it to the previous feature map, I noticed, they were not the same.

Here is the image of both the feature maps:

[image: This is the image of the feature map obtained by applying the kernel on non-rotated image]
[image: This is the image of the feature map obtained by applying the kernel on rotated image]

As you can see, they both are clearly not the same.

This means that feature maps changes as the location of features in the input image changes.

But why does this happen?
Eg: lets say we have a kernel that detects 'eye', after training the kernel on images of 'eye' present at the center of the image, we give it an image, where this time, the 'eye' is present at top-left of the image. It would still do a good job, because it would search the eye on every (5,5) part of the image (assuming the kernel is of size (5, 5)), so it shouldn't matter where the feature is present in the image.

So, why did the feature map when we changed the location of features in the input image, in the example of '5'?

Comment: Hey Dhruv, did you try to print the pixel values ? Can you provide us with your code? I think what happens is that when your filter is moving across the image, it applies some function to the pixel values selected by that filter. If you rotate that image now, a diffrent set of pixels will be selected by your filter as the filter is still moving across the image in the same way (or better direction)

Answer (score 0):

The filter is not invariant to rotation: for a window of 3×3 pixels, you have 9 weights that say how much the pixels in the window will be represented in the output and those are not invariant to rotation. If you rotated the kernel weights, the output would be the same.

Let's say you have a kernel with such weights:

```
010
000
000
```

The result is that you move all pixels one position to the bottom. If you rotate the image, apply the filter and rotate back, you have all pixels shifted to the left.

Comment: you said that 'If you rotated the kernel weights, the output would be the same', but i don't think the output would be the same because this time a different value will be multiplied by the pixel value in the window and so we would get a different output pixel.